# Value Error: Read of Closed File when Parsing Data in Google Scholar

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter, google-scholar

I am a non-cs student studying bio but I was looking into python datascience for the purposes of webscraping Google Scholar. I created a program that worked originally, yet somehow it randomly stopped working and gave me a value Error. I think it may have to do with Google being strict with bots searching their sites. Any advice and remedies would help! I am using Jupyter Notebook ipython and Python3.

Code:

```
import pip    
def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

install('BeautifulSoup4')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener

class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"

def page_citations(x):
    #number of pages of google searches that you want to run

    query = input()
    query = str(query)
    opener = AppURLopener()
    m = 0
    q = 0
    l = make_array()
    while m < x:
        response = 
        opener.open('https://scholar.google.com/scholar?
        start='+str(q)+'&q=' + query + '&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5').read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
        for word in str(soup.find_all(class_ = "gs_fl")).split():
            if word.endswith(''+ '</a>'): 
                l = np.append(l, word.strip('</a>'))
        q = q + 10
        m = m + 1
    n = make_array()

    for number in l:
        try:
            number = int(number)
            n = np.append(n, number)
        except: continue

    return n
```

Error: 
ValueError: read of closed file

Comment: Which line of code does the error get thrown? At opener.open() ?